# Nuget lib folder containing .nupkg not .dll

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

We experienced an issue with several of our Nuget packages on a developer machine. When the packages were restored, the `lib\net452` directory contained the package's `.nupkg` file, not the `.dll` contained in the package. This breaks the project references & thus, the builds.

Performing the update on the same project on a different machine worked as expected, with the `.dll` appearing in `lib\net452`.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? The only difference between environments that we could find was that the machine that was working, had Nuget Package Manager v3.2 installed, whereas the machine causing the break had Nuget Package Manager v3.5 installed.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the logs when run nuget restore?

Answer (score 0):

I tried copy the .nupkg to the lib\net452 folder directly, I get a message "The destination folder is a subfolder of the source folder" which prevent me copy the .nupkg to that folder. And I also checked this issue in my NuGet Package Manager v3.5, it works fine in my side.

So I suggest you uninstall and reinstall your NuGet Package Manager v3.5 from Tools menu -> Extensions and Updates -> Installed in Visual Studio.